# How to create a cumulative sum over multiple columns in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I have a table in Power BI desktop that I'm trying to create a cumulative sum on.  This is the SQL to create this table:

```
create table #sample
(
DOS_Month               varchar(6)
,CRD_Month              varchar(6)
,Credit_Received_Date   date
,DaysElapsed            varchar(20)
,Last_Mo_Collections    decimal(13,0)
)
insert #sample values('201707','201708','8/2/2017','01',11470)
insert #sample values('201707','201708','8/3/2017','01',2821)
insert #sample values('201707','201708','8/4/2017','01',1361)
insert #sample values('201707','201708','8/7/2017','01',9040)
insert #sample values('201707','201708','8/3/2017','02',2397)
insert #sample values('201707','201708','8/4/2017','02',5101)
insert #sample values('201707','201708','8/7/2017','02',2256)
insert #sample values('201707','',NULL,'Complete Month',1041764)
```

After adding the cumulative sum column, this table should look like this:

```
DOS_Month   CRD_Month   Credit_Received_Date    DaysElapsed Last_Mo_Collections Cumulative
$201,707    201708  8/2/2017    1   $11,470 $11,470
$201,707    201708  8/3/2017    1   $2,821  $14,291
$201,707    201708  8/4/2017    1   $1,361  $15,652
$201,707    201708  8/7/2017    1   $9,040  $24,692
$201,707    201708  8/3/2017    2   $2,397  $27,089
$201,707    201708  8/4/2017    2   $5,101  $32,190
$201,707    201708  8/7/2017    2   $2,256  $34,446
$201,707            Complete Month  $1,041,764  $1,076,210
```

How can I do this using DAX or Quick Measures?  Also, I can't use the time functions in order to sum these either since DOS_Month and CRD_Month aren't time datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should give you your desired cumulative sum column.

```
Cumulative = CALCULATE(
    SUM(Table1[Last_Mo_Collections]), 
    FILTER(
        Table1, 
        Table1[DOS_Month] = EARLIER(Table1[DOS_Month]) &&
        (
            (
                Table1[DaysElapsed] = EARLIER(Table1[DaysElapsed]) && 
                Table1[Credit_Received_Date] <= EARLIER(Table1[Credit_Received_Date])
            ) || (
                Table1[DaysElapsed] < EARLIER(Table1[DaysElapsed])
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image: Results]

The [`EARLIER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634551.aspx) function is the key (and in my opinion horribly named). From the documentation, the function...

> Returns the current value of the specified column in an outer evaluation pass of the mentioned column.